# System.Invalid**: Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro: exit code: -1 stdout: Error: 0xffffffff

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Windows 11
Build : 22000.527

[Image : Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f548T.png)

Windows Subsystem for Linux : Checked

Hyper-V : Checked

System.InvalidOperationException:
Failed to deploy distro docker-desktop to C:\Users\MohNawawi\AppData\Local\Docker\wsl\distro: exit code: -1
stdout: Error: 0xffffffff

stderr:
at Docker.ApiServices.WSL2.WslShortLivedCommandResult.LogAndThrowIfUnexpectedExitCode(String prefix, ILogger log, Int32 expectedExitCode) in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\WSL2\WslCommand.cs:line 146
at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.d__17.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 168
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.Engines.WSL2.WSL2Provisioning.d__8.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\WSL2Provisioning.cs:line 77
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.d__28.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 178
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 67
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.d__5.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 92
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.d__14.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:line 69
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.Engines.Engines.d__29.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:line 339
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at Docker.Engines.Engines.d__29.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:line 357
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Docker.ApiServices.Services.DesktopService.d__4.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\PR-17296\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\Services\DesktopService.cs:line 39

I hope someone can help me
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just had this issue and managed to fix it.  Seems like it is because a key step in the install was skipped - you probably don't have a linux distribution locally installed.  We did an uninstall of docker (v 4.5.1) and then a clean install of Docker version 4.3.0..  Then a restart of the computer.  It then prompted us to go to this page and follow the steps from step 4 onwards.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package

Comment: I have followed these steps, but still error.

However, after that I opened Hyper-V Manager and tried to install the virtual machine (from Hyper-V Manager). And I open a while later my docker can be used.

And the steps you presented, already helped me to fix Error: 0xffffffff when first installing docker.
Thank you sir

Answer (score -1):

Follow those steps:

- Uncheck Windows Subsystem for Linux in Windows Features
- Reboot
- Turn the feature back on
- Re-apply the WSL2 update
- Reboot

Source: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/8204#issuecomment-707389365

Comment: Except for the first line, the entire answer is a straight copy of the GitHub comment. Copied text *must* be clearly marked as such (that is, block quoted). Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-do-we-do-with-answers-that-are-entirely-copied-and-improperly-attributed-o)*

Comment: Otherwise, it is [plagiarism](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plagiarism#Noun): *"1. (uncountable) Copying of another person's ideas, text or other creative work, and presenting it as one's own, especially without permission; plagiarizing."*

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 1 year ago"*